# mongoDB - adding shards gives error: host does not belong to replica set

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to add a replicaset (with just one primary member, because this is only a test deployment) to my cluster, I get an error message, as you can see below:

```
me@medev:~$ mongo --host dc2-mg2.domain.org --port 27017
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.5
connecting to: dc2-mg2.domain.org:27017/test
mongos> sh.addShard("jjrs1/mghost.domain.org:27017")
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "in seed list jjrs1/mghost.domain.org:27017, host mghost.domain.org:27017 does not belong to replica set jjrs1"
}
mongos>
```

And yet, when I log into mghost.domain.org and run the mongo shell, and then check the replicaset status, I get the following results:

```
jjrs1:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "jjrs1",
    "date" : ISODate("2014-11-26T16:28:49Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "mghost:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 69680,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1417013013, 58),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-11-26T14:43:33Z"),
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1416949715, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2014-11-25T21:08:35Z"),
            "self" : true
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
jjrs1:PRIMARY>
```

Can you tell me what else I can check to verify my setup?  This error happens to all 3 replica sets that I try to add (they all only have 1 primary member). 
I have one config server... and one query router.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. 
as per the rs.status() command, the name of the mghost doesn't NOT include the domain. 
so i changed the sh.addShard command to just be:

```
sh.addShard("jjrs1/mghost:27017")
```